# Streaming audio/radio in Java?

Tags: java, audio, mp3, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I've been looking around the entire web, and tried a bunch of different stuff, but I can't figure out how to play streaming audio in java - which is crucial for the application Iam developing now. It's a radio. I've already written it for the web, but I want a desktop version, and I though java might be the way to go.

Streams look like this (mostly MP3s):
http://lyd.nrk.no/nrk_radio_mp3_mp3_h (example from NRK MP3 - a radio channel in Norway).

So where should I go from here? I've tried both JMF, FMJ and a lot of other stuff. I just want to stream audio.. 
I appreciate all answers, please help me out!

Comment: You want to read the stream (radio client) or you want to create the stream (radio channel)?

Comment: Thats right, just play the audio :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Java FX 2 (latest version is 2.1)? It has a media component that's rather easy to use. Works well for video including streaming video (even h.264 in JavaFX 2.1) in my experience. Can play normal mp3 files with it, never tried streaming mp3 though.

Comment: Yes, I would also suggest first to try JavaFX when it comes to client side multi media.

Comment: Ah. No I havent't tried it. I'll have a look at it now, but it seems to be almost a complete different language? So I need to rewrite all my code?

Comment: No, you do not need to rewrite all of your code.  Older versions of JavaFX (1.x) used a language called JavaFX Script, newer (current) versions (2.x+) are written in Java - just use the current latest Java version.

Comment: I think mp3 streaming in JavaFX currently works, (maybe aac) too.  The functionality in JavaFX 2.1 may be sufficient for you.  There are jira cases to further enhance this functionality in future releases (these are scheduled for delivery this year) - [RT-19582](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19582) "aac/aac+ radio streaming" [RT-17556](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-17556) "Support for shoutcast/icecast streaming (mp3/aac(+))" (anybody can sign up at those links to view the jira status).

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX 2 does not support mp3 streams, but you can hack it.

Open a socket connection to any ICY mp3 stream in a new thread and start saving the bytes to a file.

After a few kilobytes received open the file in the JavaFX MediaPlayer and play it, but do not stop receiving bytes on the another thread.

This is what worked for me.