# JavaFX MediaPlayer status Unknown (streaming from http) Mpeglayer3

Tags: java, javafx, media, audio-streaming, internet-radio

Im trying to make an App that streams an online radio (http://syl.mooo.com:9000/stream) (No Life Radio) but MediaPlayer won't react, if i check the status it says UNKNOWN.
What am i doing wrong?

My code:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFXPanel(); // initializes JavaFX environment
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Media media = new Media("http://syl.mooo.com:9000/stream");
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    }
}
```

}

App only consists on a button that says "Play"

**EDIT:**

After adding error handling i got:

MediaException: UNKNOWN :  [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@b1f29c7] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID:  ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.getMediaException(MediaException.java:160)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$_MediaErrorListener.onError(MediaPlayer.java:2660)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.HandleErrorEvents(NativeMediaPlayer.java:685)
    at  com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.run(NativeMediaPlayer.java:41 9)

Addded code:

```
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
          ....

            media = new Media("http://radio.nolife-radio.com:9000/stream");
            if (media.getError() == null)
            {
                media.setOnError(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        System.out.println("error media");
                    }
                });
            }
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            if (mediaPlayer.getError() == null)
            {
                mediaPlayer.setOnError(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        mediaPlayer.getError().printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
            }
           }
```

Also, sometimes it makes java crash with: APPCRASH fxplugins.dll

**EDIT2:**

it seems that shoutcast isnt supported by javafx ([Streaming audio/radio in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438351/streaming-audio-radio-in-java)) so i will try JLayer (http://www.javazoom.net/projects.html) now and update again.

Comment: Review the [JavaFX media error handling code in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) and add it to your application to try to troubleshoot your issues, also ensure that the stream is in a format JavaFX will handled as per the javadoc link in this comment. Try accessing your stream using just a plain JavaFX program rather than a Swing embedded one (just to help troubleshoot the issue).  I don't know what LibGDX has to do with your question.

Comment: Ok thanks, will do. Ill get back after i check that link. About LibGDX, it has nothing to do, just for some more info.

Comment: After adding errorHandling i got
MediaException: UNKNOWN : [com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.platform.gstreamer.GSTMediaPlayer@b1f29c7] ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID: ERROR_MEDIA_INVALID
 at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.getMediaException(MediaException.java:160)
 at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer$_MediaErrorListener.onError(MediaPlayer.java:2660)
 at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.HandleErrorEvents(NativeMediaPlayer.java:685)
 at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaPlayer$EventQueueThread.run(NativeMediaPlayer.java:419)